# How to use PHP in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $(".scratchCard").rabidScratchCard({
                foreGroundImage:"images/cards/card-prev.png",
                backgGroundImage:"images/cards/card1-3-8.png",
                revealRadius:7
        });


        });
    </script>
```

The following i want to do is, change the line of foreGroundImage to:

```
foreGroundImage:"<?php echo $path . $img ?>",
```

Do i have to use AJAX in Javascript? Or how does it work?

Comment: did you try to use `foreGroundImage:"<?php echo $path . $img ?>",`?

Comment: @UglyEddie .. Yes i did.

Comment: if your file is a .html, rename it as a .php file!

Comment: When you echo $path . $img in anywhere else.. what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the script tag is embedded within a .php page (or any file containing php that has a mime type your webserver has been configured to execute), you can interpolate PHP within the page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){
    $(".scratchCard").rabidScratchCard({
      foreGroundImage: "<?php echo $path . $img ?>",
      backgGroundImage:"images/cards/card1-3-8.png",
      revealRadius:7
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ofcourse, the file was html. Since i renamed it, its okay now. Thanks.